# When opening Git Giu on Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual Box the screen does not show the graphics correctly

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, gui, git, qt

When opening Git Giu on Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual Box the screen does not show the graphics correctly.

I have recently used the same functionality a couple days ago and I had no problem with it. I really do not know what I changed but I definitely changed something. I would really appreciate any help with it.
[image: distorred gui]

Comment: I have the same issue when running in virtual box 7.0.12 with 3d acceleration enabled. (If I don't enable 3d acceleration it displays correctly, but then I can't use my multiple 4k monitors)